# Node.js eval var json parse

Tags: json, bash, node.js

I'm trying to make a small parser which receives the json string and the path to get:

```
var args = process.argv;
var jsonToBeParsed = args[2];
var path = args[3];

var result = JSON.parse(jsonToBeParsed);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.path);
```

I'm calling this with

```
node parser.js '{"asd":"123", "qwe":"312"}' 'asd'
```

It gives me `undefined`

I think it has to be done with some eval function but I don't have too much experience with node/JS.
How can I resolve this?, I need to get the result from the command line.

Edit: I'm expecting "123" in the second log. Thanks @Esailija, the question wasn't too clear ...

Comment: Works fine for me, of course there is no `path` in the json so that logs `undefined` as expected

Comment: Have you read my comments?, or even the title of the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to use dynamic property, you cannot use `.path`, because that literally means `.path` property.

Try this:

```
console.log(result);
console.log(result[path]);
```

if `path === "asd"`, then it will work, which is statically equivalent to `result["asd"]` or `result.asd`

Comment: Thanks Esailija. Another question here:
if I have a Json like {"asd":{"qwe":"123", "ert":"465"}}
I tried result["asd"]["qwe"] and gives me the right value "123". But are there other way to retrieve the value?(I'm trying some expresion like result[asd.qwe] but with no luck)

Comment: @Federico `result[path1][path2]` if `path1` is `"asd"` and `"path2"` is `"qwe"`

Comment: yes that works, but is there a way to do it in this way result[asd.qwe] ?? Because I want to call that app with 2 arguments, the JSON, and the complete path (i.e. "asd.qwe")

Comment: Well, you'd have to also parse your input for dots and split the paths on the dots. Something like pathArray = args[3].split('.'); and then constructing the query based on the length of the array etc.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Esailija's answer:

```
node parser.js '{"path": "123"}' 'asd'
```

Would return `123`. The dot notation expects the property name. If you have a dynamic property name, you need to use the square brackets notation.

```
console.log(result['ads']);
// But what you want is:
console.log(result[path]); // 'path' is a variable with the correct string
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to embed the json parser into a git alias, To get a json node in bash (using node)

`node -e "console.log(JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).foo.bar)" '{"foo":{"bar":"Hello World"}}'`

Comment: Can also use `node -p` to get rid of the `console.log()`.